# how to fix this exception ；Caused by ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31 cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.Produces

Tags: grails, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm working on a spring-data-neo4j project ,and this project is developed by java ,but I want to change to grails for its productivity.I copy the following applicationContext.xml content into grails applicationContext.xml:

```
    <!--Custom Configuration-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
<!--    <context:component-scan base-package="com.turingmac">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>-->

    <!-- Neo4j configuration (creates Neo4jTemplate) -->
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data"/>
    </bean>

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.turingmac.repository"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>
```

but i got this error:

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean
>   property 'graphDatabaseService'; 
>       nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31 cannot be cast to
>   javax.ws.rs.Produces Message: Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'graphDatabaseService' while setting bean
>   property 'graphDatabaseService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31 cannot be cast to
>   javax.ws.rs.Produces** Caused by BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31 cannot be cast to
>   javax.ws.rs.Produces Caused by ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31 cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.Produces

and I tried a lot of methods ,e.g. upgrading springframework version ,adding extra jars,it does't work.

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then I happen to stumble across this exception, and usually I delete the folder. slcache as per http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9952 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15954077/757413