# Is Grails 2.2 worth using for serious and complex web application development?

Tags: grails

We are contemplating using grails for our next project.  But we are not sure if it is mature enough to use.

We have googled and even seen few existing posts on SO where people are saying good  and bad things, but i guess they were old posts and articles.

As of 2013, and grails 2.2 release are there any concerns which we should consilder before moving to grails?

Comment: Similar question was asked 3.5 years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397228/is-grails-worth-it - since then its been bought by Spring Source... FYI, I'm voting to close this question, as it "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" - see the FAQ.

Comment: +1 nickdos. I second it.